# Inherit parent constructor arguments

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, arguments

I'm browsing the discussion for a similar topic, but can't find my situation...

Am trying call parent constructors with parameters... can't seem to get it right.

I have a `PhysicsBody` superclass that takes `aNode` as its only constructor argument:

```
function PhysicsBody(aNode) {
    this.userData = aNode;
    // ...
}
```

Of this `PhysicsBody` inherits a `DynamicBody` class. Is constructor also takes `aNode` as only argument... Like I would do it in Java, I'd love to call something equivalent to `"super(aNode");` Can't seem to find out how.

Here's the `DynamicBody` class:

```
// Wanted to give "new PhysicsBody(this, aNode)", but that fails!
DynamicBody.prototype = new PhysicsBody();
DynamicBody.prototype.constructor=DynamicBody;

function DynamicBody(aNode) {

    // calling the parent constructor fails too:
    // PhysicsBody.prototype.constructor.call(this, aNode);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
function PhysicsBody( aNode ) {
    this.userData = aNode;
}

PhysicsBody.prototype.pbMethod = function () {};

function DynamicBody( aNode ) {
    PhysicsBody.call( this, aNode );
}

// setting up the inheritance
DynamicBody.prototype = Object.create( PhysicsBody.prototype );

DynamicBody.prototype.dbMethod = function () {};
```

---

Now, when you do

```
var pb = new PhysicsBody( '...' );
```

the instance `pb` gets a `userData` property and also inherits the methods from `PhysicsBody.prototype` (`pbMethod` in this case).

[image]

---

When you do

```
var db = new DynamicBody( '...' );
```

the instance `db` gets a `userData` property and also inherits the methods from `DynamicBody.prototype` (`dbMethod` in this case), which in turn inherits from `PhysicsBody.prototype`.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! This has illuded me since ancient time, yet it was so simple.. *faceslap*

Comment: @Lars-Erik To be honest, it's a mess :-). The upcoming edition of JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) will bring class syntax, which will make this pattern much simpler.

Comment: Then we're just left with the 10 year waiting period before all browsers with pre v6 are dead. :)
I still like this way of "deriving classes" better than the various extend functions etc. (for now at least)

Comment: @Lars-Erik Feel free to start using ES6 classes **today** with a ES6-to-Es5 transpliler. You can transpile in-browser, or before with e.g. a Grunt task https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-traceur

Comment: still I don't understand how come it works - why is the DynamicBody an instanceof PhysicsBody? they both inherit from object but they do not inherit from each other! (assuming that PhysicsBody.prototype points to a generic Object...)

Comment: Why do we need to do `DynamicBody.prototype = Object.create( PhysicsBody.prototype );` instead of just `DynamicBody.prototype = PhysicsBody.prototype;` ? - EDIT: Ah, its so we don't clobber the parent prototype when adding methods to `DynamicBody`'s prototype.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you correctly, by saying you want to inherit the parent constructor arguments, you mean that `new DynamicBody(1, 2, 3)` will internally call `PhysicsBody(1, 2, 3)` for the `DynamicBody` instance.

This can be accomplished by using `.apply` and passing `arguments` along: http://jsfiddle.net/pmkrQ/.

```
function DynamicBody() {
    PhysicsBody.apply(this, arguments);
}
```