# javascript inheritance why use Object.create?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I saw this in StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7786090/289246

The answer tells to do:

```
DynamicBody.prototype = Object.create( PhysicsBody.prototype );
```

What is the reason to use Object.create?
Why can't we just use:

```
DynamicBody.prototype = PhysicsBody.prototype;
```

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045080/javascript-inheritance-calling-object-create-when-setting-a-prototype/15045616#15045616

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can (technically), but then any change you make to `DynamicBody.prototype` will also be made on `PhysicsBody.prototype`, i.e. it will affect all `PhysicsBody` instances, and that is usually not what you want.

Example:

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.say = function() {
   alert('Foo');
};
var foo = new Foo();

function Bar() {};
Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;
Bar.prototype.say = function() {
    alert('Bar');
};

foo.say(); // alerts 'Bar'
```

`Object.create` adds one level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has prototype based inheritance. Which means, inheritance occurs from objects directly, unlike classical inheritance which inherits from a class.

When you do this:

`Foo.protoype = Bar.prototype` - you are inheriting all vars and methods from `Bar` object.. but any change to `Foo`'s prototype will result in `Bar`'s prototype to be changed(since due to above statement, `Foo.prototype` references `Bar.prototype`).

`Object.create()` is used to add classical inheritance like property to `Foo`. So instead of inheriting from the object directly, you are inheriting from `Object` with a specified prototype. And any change to `Foo` after the statement `Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype)` will not change `Bar`.

see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for more info!

Comment: I wouldn't say that using `Object.create` is "classical inheritance like". It just creates an object with a specific prototype, which is the same what every constructor function does.