# Javascript constructors inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Good Morning in my timezone.

I am learning JavaScript inheritance and i start reading the MDN pages.
I understand that we have to use the prototype property from the constructor to build a inheritance chain, for example :

```
function Employee(){
 this.name = "Dave";
 this.dept = "";
}

function Manager(){
 this.projects = [];
}
Manager.prototype = new Employee;
```

If we do this :

```
var jane = new Manager();
```

jane.name -> It will retrive "Dave" because it will find on the Employee object.

What i can not understand is if you do this way:

```
 function Employee(name,dept){
 this.name = name || "Dave";
 this.dept = dept || "General";
}

function Manager(){
 this.base = Employee;
 this.base("Jack","CustpmDept");
 this.projects = [];
}
```

Now if i do the same :

```
var jane = new Manager();
```

jane.name -> It will retrive "Jack" because it will find on the Employee object.

In this last example i did not use the line Manager.prototype = new Employee;
And it stil works , the Manager object have as their prototype object the Employee object.
How is this possible ?
Can you clarify me

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7786090/1882644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following code:

```
function Employee(name,dept){
    this.name = name || "Dave";
    this.dept = dept || "General";
    console.log(this instanceof Manager);
}

function Manager(){
     this.base = Employee;
     this.base("Jack","CustpmDept");
     this.projects = [];
}

var jane = new Manager();
console.log(jane.name);
```

In the example

```
console.log(this instanceof Manager);
```

returns *true* because when you call

```
this.base = Employee;
```

you are basically sending Manager's *this* to the *Employee*. *this.name* and *this.dept* are actually attached to the *Manager*.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Manager(){
    this.base = Employee;
    this.base("Jack","CustpmDept");
    this.projects = [];
}
```

when you used the `this.base("Jack","CustpmDept")`, in invokes the `Employee` with `this` inside the `Employee` pointing to the new manager instance

Answer (score 1):

The second way is like constructor stealing. `this.base("Jack","CustpmDept");` will call the `Employee` constructor, since `this` key word will point to the object to be creates when we new the instance, so jane can get these properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the latter, `new Manager()` returns 'Jack' because you call `this.Employee('Jack', 'CustpmDept')` which sets `jane.name` to 'Jack', because 'this' is 'Manager', or in this case, 'jane'.

It's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

OK so js is fun with how it handles context.

When you call `this.base()` in the Managers 'constructor' you are calling the function `base` from the context of that manager. So by the time we get to the `this.name =` bit, the keyword `this` refers back to that manager, not the function that line was written in.