# Inherit and use super class's constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I wonder if it's possible to instantiate subclasses in javascript by automatically using the super class's constructor.
Consider this (inspired by [this other question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785955/inherit-parent-constructor-arguments)):

```
function A(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
}
A.prototype.whatAmI = function() {
    console.log(
        "I'm an instance of %s, my prop is %s",
        this instanceof A1? "A1" : "A2",
        this.prop
    );
};

function A1() {
    A.apply(this, arguments);
}
A1.prototype = new A();
A1.prototype.constructor = A1;

function A2() {
    A.apply(this, arguments);
}
A2.prototype = new A();
A2.prototype.constructor = A2;

var a1 = new A1("foo").whatAmI(); //I'm an instance of A1, my prop is foo
var a2 = new A2("bar").whatAmI(); //I'm an instance of A2, my prop is bar
```

However, referring to [this article](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html), in the first example I came across this line of code:

```
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
//Otherwise instances of Cat would have a constructor of Mammal
```

I thought that's exactly what I needed: that instances of `A1` and `A2` have the constructor of `A`. Unfortunately commenting out `A1.prototype.constructor = A1` and emptying `A1`'s body (same goes for `A2`) does not work:

```
function A1() {}
A1.prototype = new A();

function A2() {}
A2.prototype = new A();

var a1 = new A1("foo").whatAmI(); //I'm an instance of A1, my prop is undefined
var a2 = new A2("bar").whatAmI(); //I'm an instance of A2, my prop is undefined
```

Finally, changing `A`'s constructor to use the `arguments` object instead of explicitly passing `prop` has no effect either:

```
function A() {
    this.prop = arguments[0];
}
```

Is it even possible, with a little fiddling around with the `prototype` property, to achieve what I want?

Comment: why did you empty the bodies? just don't reset the constructor and you should have the result u want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
> //Otherwise instances of Cat would have a constructor of Mammal
> ```
>
> I thought that's exactly what I needed: that instances of A1 and A2
>   have the constructor of A.

No, that's not what they meant. The `A1` and `A2` functions *are* still their own constructors that are getting invoked, and you cannot change that.

The problem that the article describes is that the `.constructor` property that all instances inherit *to point out their constructor* is no longer valid when you overwrite `AX.prototype`. See also [What is the `constructor` property really used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12622137/1048572) (and linked questions).

> Unfortunately commenting out `A1.prototype.constructor = A1` and
>   emptying A1's body (same goes for A2) does not work.

By emptying the body, it doesn't do anything any more. You still will need to call `A` explicitly, you won't get around that. What you could do is create a generic factory that creates subclasses for `A` that don't do anything special, but I don't think it's worth it.

Oh, and not to forget: [You should not use `new` for creating prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)!

```
subclass(parent) {
    function Child() {
        parent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    return Child;
}
```

```
function A(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
}
A.prototype.whatAmI = function() {
    console.log(
        "I'm an instance of %s, my prop is %s",
        this instanceof A1? "A1" : "A2",
        this.prop
    );
};
var A1 = subclass(A),
    A2 = subclass(A);
```