# can a literal object inherit from class?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, object-literal

So I was thinking if a literal object can inherit properties and methods from a class. Here is the code

```
var Foo = function(val1, val2) {
    this.prop1 = val1;
    this.prop2 = val2;
}

var bar = {
    //how to inherit properties from Foo class; also add new property
    prop3: 'val3'
};
```

Comment: @Jonasw Though this may not be a question suitable for SO, I was wondering how those of us who were taught to learn by asking questions are supposed to keep up with the obviously superior people like you who apparently just learn things? Maybe you can instruct us on your superior "Don't ask questions to learn" technique? (Sorry I asked 2 questions there, I don't know any other way)

Comment: @gforce301 No! Please still ask. Im glad to help.  But the question looks like as he will find his answer in the next chapter of his book/part of his tutorial. And its not his first question today...

Comment: _"please learn first, then ask. Looks like youre currently doing learning by asking"_ ? Of course one can learn by asking. There is no monopoly on the routes to learning. If one already is learned, why would they need to ask any questions at all? Except to themselves

Comment: @guest271314 im sorry, was maybe a bit to rude

Comment: Im not going throught any book. I just have this question and I couldn't find anywehere. so I decided to post here my question. but thanks anyway

Comment: @user271314 i appreciate that feedback. error backward propagated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating an instance of `Foo` and then adding properties to that instance like so:

```
var Foo = function(val1, val2) {
    this.prop1 = val1;
    this.prop2 = val2;
}

var x = new Foo('valOfProp1', 'valOfProp2');

x.prop3 = 'valOfAddedProp';
```

Comment: but It will still be a literal object if I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no inheritance in your code. Inheritance would look like this:

```
var Foo = function(val1, val2) {}
Foo.prototype={
    prop1:val1,
    prop2:val2
};

var bar = {
//how to inherit properties from Foo class; also add new property
prop3: val3
};
```

And now you could do:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, /*to*/ Foo.prototype);
```

or creating another object:

```
var instance=new Foo();
Object.assign(instance,bar);
```

Comment: actually I was thinking of doing something like this:

`var Foo = function(val1, val2) {
  this.prop1 = val1;
   this.prop2 = val2;
};

var bar = {
 prop3: 'val3',
 inherit_from_Foo: function(val1, val2) {
  Foo.call(this, val1, val2);
 }
};`

Comment: @vincent thorpe so you want inheritance from a constructor function?

Comment: @vincent thorpe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785955/inherit-parent-constructor-arguments

Comment: Not necessarily I just trying to find a way to do inheritance from class to a literal object

Comment: @vincent thorpe then you could go with setPrototypeOf wich simply sets the[[proto]] prototype

Comment: but It will still be a literal object if I do that?. because I just will have a single object with all properties from a class, plus aditional properties and methods. I heard that literal objects have a better performance than constructors

Comment: @vincent thorpe everything is an object in js. it does not matter how you do it, js uses prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var Foo = function(val1, val2) {
    this.prop1 = val1;
    this.prop2 = val2;
};

Foo.prototype.getProp = function(p){
  return this[p]; // NOT!! this.p
};

var bar = {
    //how to inherit properties from Foo class; also add new property
    prop3: "val3"
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(bar,Foo.prototype);
console.log(bar.getProp("prop1"));
console.log(bar.getProp("prop2"));
console.log(bar.getProp("prop3"));
```